# Converting from m/d/y format date to Unix timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to come up with a way to use PHP to convert any date that is in a format below, to a unix timestamp. I was wondering if someone can help me accomplish this.

This is what I tried, which didn't work:

```
   $expiration_date = '11/22/12';

   $timestamp = strtotime(date("m/d/y", $expiration_date));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `date()` part.

Just do this:

```
$expires = '11/22/12';
$unix = strtotime($expires);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

The problem with your example is you're passing a string to the `date()` function.
The `date()` function requires a format string e.g. `'m/d/y'` and then the time as an int value.
You're passing it a string so it doesn't work.

`date()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Please use DateTime for these operations.

```
$expiration_date = '11/22/12';
list($m, $d, $y) = explode('/', $expiration_date);
$unix = (checkdate((int)$m, (int)$d, (int)$y + 2000)) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $expiration_date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->getTimestamp() : false;
echo $unix;
```

This will give you an integer.

Comment: Now I've condensed it to 1 line, to avoid any confusing meta variables :P

Comment: Same here, programming would be the career choice of owls!

Comment: No you haven't... it's 3 lines! Why not scrap all the vars and just do: print DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', '11/22/12', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->getTimestamp(); ?

Comment: I guess I "liked" your comment above :D

Comment: Umm, the 1st line is the start var which can come from anywhere I guess, so I left it, and the end echo is just for fun :P

Comment: Also, you could add checks for incase the date is invalid and the timestamp fails...